# Remove google maps controls

Tags: android, google-maps

my question is quite easy, but I haven't found the answer yet. I need to remove these controls from the map:

[image: Map Controls]

They appear when I press on my marker. This is my code of setting up the map.

```
        mMap = ((MapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

        // Showing / hiding your current location
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(false);

        // Enable / Disable zooming controls
        mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);

        // Enable / Disable my location button
        mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);

        // Enable / Disable Compass icon
        mMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);

        // Enable / Disable Rotate gesture
        mMap.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(true);

        // Enable / Disable zooming functionality
        mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);

        mMap.setPadding(0, 150, 0, 150);
```

Comment: Why you have enabled compass may be that one you have to set as false.

Comment: @Clairvoyant I've tried it right now. But these controls are still in place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the documentation you can use the method *setMapToolbarEnabled* . So you need to add the following line:

```
mMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(false);
```

Comment: There is no such method =(

Comment: Thanks, `mMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(false);` made the trick!

Answer (score 0):

you could also set this in xml

```
<fragment       xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"          
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
...
                map:uiMapToolbar="false"
...
/>
```